# Replace an optional word / expression from a string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I replace the following optional word/ expression from a given string in php?

Given string - `Client Side: ABC Client` or `Client Side : XYZ Client`

Now I want to replace expression from the given word - `Client Side:` or `Client Side :` Difference between both of them is that, one word ends with colon `$word:` and another ends with a extra space and colon `$word :`

So how can I write a regeX to resolve this problem. ?
I have tried with `str_replace`, but it would multiple `str_replace` to do that. I want a clean and simple regeX using `preg_replace` to replace the given expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use following regex

```
preg_replace('/\bClient Side\s?:\B/','',$str);
```

Here I've used `\bClient Side\s?:\B` regex. Within this regex `\s?` will check for optional space if yes then also its get matches and if not then also it'll match the given string along with word boundaries

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/yR7kD7/1)

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/438941)

Comment: Why are you using `\B` after the colon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` in the following manner to resolve the problem.

```
$string = "Client Side: ABC System"; //either this string or 2nd string
$string = "Client SideL : XYZ System";

preg_replace("/Client Site[ ]*[:]/", '', $string)
```

explanation of parameters used -

```
/Client Side        # Start searching with this word
[ ]                 # An optional blank space parameter
*                   # Any number of occurrence of blank space
[:]                 # Replace colon when it occurs
```

for brief description of parameters please refer to following URL - http://www.hackingwithphp.com/4/8/6/regular-expression-syntax-examples